# Custom Tabs on Magento 1.7.0.0 Product Page

Tags: php, html, xml, e-commerce

I'm trying to add several custom tabs to my product page on Magento commerce, followed other tutorials but haven't seen anything that helped me.

As it specifies in [this tutorial](http://jonmarquis.com/custom-tabs-on-magento-product-pages/) I'd to add few custom tabs like: **DESCRIPTION**, **SUPPLEMENT FACTS**, **LABEL**, **RATING AND REVIEWS** and **Q & A** (from tutorial link)

customtab.phtml has:

```
<?php
//Load the product
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct()
//Get additional data if the product has it
if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()):
//Finally, get the attribute label and close your if statement. Remember to change ingredients to the label you created.
?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('customtab')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Note: 'customtab' is already added as an attribute to my default attribute sets

for layout, I have:

```
        <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml"><br/>
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                    <alias>customtab</alias>
                    <title>Custom Tab</title>
                    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
                    <template>catalog/product/view/customtab.phtml</templat>
                </action>
            </block>
```

Any idea how to add that custom tabs?

Comment: do you have any tabs to start with? (eg modern theme)? Do you have the required javascript and styling anywhere?